# Is there any way to get the registered custom post types name?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a couple of custom post types in WordPress and would like to get a list of all the custom post types created on the site, however, the function that you would think is for this, doesn't return custom post types at all.

```
get_post_types();
```

That does not return the custom post type names.

The custom post is registered like this:

```
function custom_post_type_test() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label'  => 'Test' );
    register_post_type( 'testtype', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type_test' );
```

I have searched everywhere on the internet but cannot find a solution anywhere!
Any one have any information on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_post_types()` but set the `_builtin` parameter to false, like this:

```
$args = array( '_builtin' => false );
$post_types = get_post_types( $args );
```

Setting `_builtin` to false tells WordPress to exclude the built-in post types and only return the custom ones.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work, if you have a wordpress installation you can control, try copy/pasting the registered post type I created, and then try your code out.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('admin_init', function(){
    $args = array( '_builtin' => false );
    $post_types = get_post_types( $args ); 
    var_dump($post_types);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

after some research i found the issue and solution, too. that i am sharing to you.

i found that problem is not by get_post_types function. it is the problem where we use to call this function. i describe it, clearly.

1. create a function

   `function get_all_custom_post_types(){

   ```
   $args = array('public' => true  ,'_builtin' => false    );

   $output = 'objects';//'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default

   $operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

   $custom_post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );           

   $post_types = array();

   foreach ( $custom_post_types   as $k => $post_type ) {

       $post_types = $post_type;

   }           

   return $post_types ;
   ```

   }`
2. use this custom function where you want to call this, but use only in any wordpress action or filter callback function. like when create a callback function add_metabox action, then call this function.
   `add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_mb_option');

   function add_mb_option(){

   ```
   add_meta_box('mb-option', 'custom metabox detail', 'add_mb_option_element',
       'custom_metabox', 'normal', 'high');
   ```

   }

   function add_mb_option_element(){

   $cpts = get_all_custom_post_types();
   // more custom code will goes here
   }`

very simple to use.

happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can get it in admin as well as on front end too

```
    add_action('admin_init', function(){
      $post_types = get_post_types( array( 'public' => true ), 'names' ); 
      var_dump($post_types);
    });
```